# Distance between two partitions of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-partition

I want to compare two different partitions of a set consisting of $n$ elements: ${1,2,3,...,n}$. How can I count the number of elements that are in different subsets when comparing partition 1 with partition 2?

Examples with $n=6$

Partition 1: $\{\{1,2,3\},\{4,5,6\}\}$, partition 2: $\{\{1,2,4\},\{3,5,6\}\}$ should yield $2$ since the elements $3$ and $4$ are in different subset.

Partition 1: $\{\{1,2,3\},\{4,5,6\}\}$, partition 2: $\{\{1,2\},\{3\},\{4,5,6\}\}$ should yield $1$ since the element $3$ is in a different subset.

Partition 1: $\{\{1,2,3\},\{4,5,6\}\}$, partition 2: $\{\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\}$ should yield $3$ since the elements $4,5,6$ are in different subsets.

Background:
I want to compare two different community partitions of a network. I would like to know how many nodes I have to "move" to a different community to get from one partition to the other. [In this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZSSD.jpg) you can see a possible community partition (the communities are color-coded, i.e. nodes with the same color belong to the same community).

Comment: Your concept of "in different sets" is not well-defined. It is based on an Identification of sets in the first partition with sets in the second partition which you have been making subconsciously, but have no solid rules for defining. For example, I could claim in the 2nd example that 3, 4, 5, 6 are all in different sets, as 3 moved from the first set to the second, while 4, 5, and 6 all moved from the second set to the third.

Comment: I agree. Lets say we have the solutions (i.e. the number of elements) for all possible identifications of subsets. Then I would like to get just the minimum. Then I should be well-defined, I think. In the example it would still yield $1$ since $1 = min(\{1;4;$ [other possible solutions]$\})$.

Comment: Could you explain the background of your problem?

Comment: @md2perpe I've updated my question.

Comment: How do you know $3$ and $4$ are in different subsets? Maybe they are in the original subsets and the four other elements moved to the other set.

Comment: @Leonardo, is one cluster of points, e.g. the green to the right, one set in a partition?

Comment: @fleablood, it seems according to a comment above that Leonardo considers the smallest change.

Comment: @md2perpe Yes. The network consists of 44 communities which are color-coded. So the community partition consists of 44 subsets.

Comment: @fleablood As md2perpe said, I am looking for the smallest change.

Comment: Then a partition is not just of anonymous sets but each part of it is labelled so $\{ \{ 1,2,3 \}, \{ 4, 5, 6 \} \}$ and $\{ \{ 4, 5, 6 \}, \{ 1, 2, 3 \} \}$ are different partitions? In the first case nodes 1,2,3 belong to community 1 and nodes 4,5,6 to community 2. In the second case nodes 4,5,6 belong to community 1 and nodes 1,2,3 to community 2. Correct?

Comment: @md2perpe No, these are not two different partitions but the same. A partition is a relational property. So the labelling of the communities doesn't play a role. It is only important to know which nodes are in the same community. It is not important how you call the community (community1 or community2 or something else).

Comment: I know that the problem is not well-defined without any labeling of the subsets. That is why I am looking for the smallest change, which is the most intuitive. Then it becomes well-defined again.

Comment: Is this "how can I count..." in the sense that you're wondering what is a good definition, or you're wondering what's an (efficient?) way to actually get a computer to calculate such a thing, once you have a definition?

Comment: The second. I just want to calculate it. Sorry if there were misunderstandings. I posted this question here because I thought there could be a nice "mathematical" way of treating this problem. Also, I have no idea how to solve this problem using an algorithm. That algorithm would have to consider all possible cases and find the smallest change. For larger networks this would become impractical as the number of possible community identifications becomes too large to compare them all (at least I think so).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be transformed into an [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem).

Solution: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6569/edit-distance-between-two-partitions

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Call the partition with the largest number of parts $P_1$, the first partition (if it's a tie, pick whichever)
- Arbitrarily label the parts in $P_1$.
- Starting with a largest part $p$ of the second partition $P_2$, find a part $p'$ of $P_1$ so that $p \cap p'$ is as large as possible (if there is a tie, break it however). Label $p$ with the same label as $p'$
- Repeat the preceding step until all of the parts in the second partition are labeled, never reusing labels within $P_2$.

This won't in general be unique.

For example:
$$
\text{Partition 1: } 
\{\underbrace{\{1,2\}}_{A},\underbrace{\{3\}}_{B},\underbrace{\{4,5,6\}}_{C}\}
\qquad 
\text{Partition 2: } 
\{\underbrace{\{1,2,3\}}_{A},\underbrace{\{4,5,6\}}_{C}\}
$$

Then, you can think of each partition as a bunch of orderd pairs:

$P_1 = (1, A), (2, A), (3, B), (4, C), (5, C), (6, C)$ for the first, and

$P_2 = (1, A), (2, A), (3, A), (4, C), (5, C), (6, C)$ for the second.

Viewing these partitions as the set of ordered pairs, then the $1$ just so happens to be $|P| - |P_1 \setminus P_2| = n - |P_1 \setminus P_2|$; $n$ minus the number of things belonging to sets with the same label. In general, I believe $n - |P_1 \setminus P_2|$ should count the number of differences, as you've described it. I've tried to think of a pair of partitions for which this technique won't work, but haven't been able to.

Disclaimers:

1. I'm not sure this works, although I suspect it does. Hopefully since you have a vested interest in the problem, you can try to implement this, and see if it works as it should -- it does in all of the test cases, and one additional test case I tried: $1\ 2\ 3\ 4 \mid 5\ 6\ 7\ 8 \longrightarrow 1\ 2 \mid 3\ 4 \mid 5\ 6 \mid 7\ 8$, which (I think) is $6$ differences.
2. The part I'm least confident with is the extent to which the labeling of parts in the second partition affects things. I said "largest first" because you want to match labels for remaining parts that are the most similar. It's possible that this "greedy approach" to labeling $P_2$ will cause something to go awry, but I don't think so.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and thinking about the problem. Your solution works well for most cases, however there a cases where it fails. Example: $\{\{1,2,3,4\},\{5,6,7,8\}\}$ and $\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3,4,5,6,7,8\}\}$ would yield $6$ moves for your algorithm. However you actually only need $3$ moves. I tried to improve your algorithm by improving the "decision-making", however there are always cases where it fails. It can't be solved that way.